# Find the smallest prime number $p$ such that both $2002-p$ and $2002+p$ also are prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find the smallest prime number $p$ such that both $2002-p$ and $2002+p$ are prime. I can only get as far as finding that the sum of the two primes is $4004$. I can't think of another way other than blind guessing and I need the steps for my homework :(

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I consider this to be a bit of a trick question. Think about the values $2002-p$, $2002+p$ and $p$ modulo $3$ (i.e., the remainders when divided by $3$).

Comment: Since the author wrote that it is a homework, I avoided to provide the full explanation, but the raw solution is inside my answer (literally). $3$ cases where everything is a multiple of $2$ or $3$, but $p$ even doesn't work... so the only multiple of $3$ that is prime is $3$ itself and $2002-p=3$ provides the answer.

Comment: no blind guessing needed. just iterate through all primes from 2 to 2004, from smallest to greatest, until you find one that works.

Answer (score 1):

Because $p$ is prime, we wil look at some cases

- $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \to 3 \mid 2002-p $ so $2002-p=3 \to p=1999$
- $p \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \to 3\mid 2002+p ; 2002+p>3 \implies 2002+p$ is a composite
- $p=3$, this satisfies the conditions.

Therefore, $p=3$